# Insert Multiple Rows RockMongo

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I just installed RockMongo on my OpenShift app. I am trying to create some of the collections manually, however the collection insert view does not seem to be able to insert multiple rows at a time.

I have tried searching around but could not find any spec/wiki to help me.

The Array option seems to be for creation of an Object in the PHP array format.

Here are the JSON options I have tried so far.

```
{name: "Object 1", category: "Cat 1"},
{name: "Object 2", category: "Cat 2"}
```

Result: Only added the last object into the database

```
[
    {name: "Object 1", category: "Cat 1"},
    {name: "Object 1", category: "Cat 1"}
]
```

Result: Added it all as one object with two objects inside it.

Does anyone know a way to use the `Insert` option in RockMongo to insert multiple items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because I was unable to use the `Insert` view to bring in an array of data. I ended up just using the `Import` feature of RockMongo.

The file I imported looked like the following:

```
db.mycollection.insert([
    {"name": "Object 1", category: "Cat 1"},
    {"name": "Object 2", category: "Cat 2"}
]);
```

Corresponding to the example data I posted in the question. Where `mycollection` is the collection you are importing the data to.